# how to search inside a list in SP2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

I have a list with many columns.I want to create a search page.
 user able to enter/select date from, date to(same date field),department,status based on the selection/input I need to display the search result in list view.

Help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this out of the box.

1. Add a HTML form web part and use it to get search input from user
2. Add a list view web part and connect it to the filter web part.

https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Use-the-HTML-Form-Web-Part-to-filter-and-display-data-in-another-Web-Part-860b681c-38ad-43ff-a036-a60868497ff7